# How to get data from custom dialog to activity?

Tags: android, dialog, android-arrayadapter

I open a dialog from a custom adapter of button click in row item.

In the dialog I update that item.

My all data comes from SQLite Database.

The problem is the dialog updates data in the database and get dismissed but the adapter is not notified. So I don't get updated value in that item after dialog is dismissed.

How can I fix this?

Any help will highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show some relevant code that you currently use

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually. Just add this line somewhere in your dialog:

```
((BaseAdapter) yourListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

To call it on the UI-Thread, use the runOnUiThread() of Activity.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular function for refreshing adapter values is notifyDataSetChanged(). Have you tried to call this one on your custom adapter after you update values in your dialog?

Another thing you can try to do is to populate the adapter with all the new values, so after you edit an item in dialog, you get all items together from database again and set up a new adapter for a listview (with new values) and them use it by calling listview.setAdapter(adapterwithnewvalues)

This answer is not really any specific solution to your problem, it is just an idea what you could try :)